# How do I ensure that Homebrew uninstalls old versions when upgrading?

Tags: macos, package-management, homebrew

[Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) seems to install new versions side by side with old versions when upgrading outdated versions (`brew upgrade`), at least I have a bunch of packages with multiple versions. How do I ensure that old versions are removed and not kept around when upgrading?

Is there support for auto-removal of outdated versions at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`brew cleanup` is your friend for this. Check out the answer I gave in a related question [here](https://superuser.com/a/975878/175099).

`brew install` in and of itself doesn't appear to have options for this. This might be a useful feature so [I](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/44288) requested it from the publisher.

Comment: I do know about `cleanup`; what I was really wondering is if brew can be made to remove outdated versions automatically when upgrading instead.

Comment: `install` in and of itself doesn't appear to have options for this. This might be a useful feature to request.

Comment: I'd add that to your answer :)

Comment: @aknuds1, it appears that this has been implemented! Check out https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/44305.